# What is this 2×8 plate slotted, rectangular studs and a hole in the middle?

Tags: part-identification

Please help to identify this part. What is its use?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is

[Part # 767 : Train, Track Sleeper Plate 2 x 8 without Cable Grooves](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=767#T=C&C=10)

or

[Part# 4166 : Train, Track Sleeper Plate 2 x 8 with Cable Grooves](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4166#T=C)

depending on the cable grooves.

It is used  to attach train tracks

Comment: You can see the cable grooves in the image.